# nginx php 5 and upload_max_files

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, upload

Hi i am running up the walls i have nginx and a php-fpm Installation

when i run Wordpress i get a 3MB Upload Limit in phpinfo() i find

```
upload_max_filesize 3M
```

At the Top i found

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/fpm
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
```

And my Volltextsuche.sh will do a

```
fgrep -nR $1 *
```

So i did a Fulltext Search but the Result is :

```
root:/etc# . Volltextsuche.sh "upload_max_filesize"
php5/fpm/php.ini:806:upload_max_filesize = 48M
php5/cli/php.ini:805:upload_max_filesize = 12M
php5/apache2/php.ini:805:upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

So now i have absolutely no clue where the nginx or php installation gets the 3MB Limit any hints are welcome !

So i know that nginx keeps client_max_body_size but it's still enough i guess

```
nginx/nginx.conf:22:    client_max_body_size 48m;
```

The upload_max_filesize seems to be ok - apache2 will not be loaded see Block 2 for that

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 48M
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 12M
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

thx in advance

Comment: What is your `post_max_size` in PHP?

Comment: Nginx also caps it: client_max_body_size 5M I'm not sure what your Volltextsuche.sh script exactly does, but also try 'grep -i -r upload_max_filesize /etc', sudo if necessary. If Apache is at all involved, you may also have to grep in your www folder as htaccess may be overriding it. Indeed, check post_max_size too though that doesn't explain why it shows 3M on phpinfo.

Comment: post_max_size  is in phpinfo 8M